# node mailer: Cannot set property mailer of undefined

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer 4.4.2 version and node 7.4.0[image] When try to run the application i am getting Cannot set property mailer of undefined error in the nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js file. What is the reason for this issue

Comment: Have you created transporter, as by error, transporter is not defined.

Comment: transporter is undefined.

Comment: Can you please update your post withyour `nodemailer` initialization code? (I mean your.. `nodemailer.createTransport.....`)?